# How do I send an envoy?

Tags: civilization-6

How do I send an envoy to a city state?  The game tells me I have two but the options are grayed out?
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are currently looking at the City-State Details screen -- which is to say, at a specific city state. You need to look at the City-States Overview tab instead, found by pressing the button circled in this picture:[image]

From this tab, available Envoys will be placeable by pressing the + / - buttons next to their name under the "Envoys" heading. (Actual buttons are not drawn in MS Paint)

Comment: thank you... just found it was coming back to answer the arrows where not obvious as in your pic.

Comment: Kind of ridiculous as someone who has a computer science degree and someone who is quite knowledgeable in UI/UX principles that it took me this long to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: what if there is no minus or plus button even when we hover over. how do we gain new envoys?

Comment: This took me forever to figure out on a Nintendo Switch: you have to press the left and right arrows on the D-Pad to assign Envoys to a city-state.  I had eight Envoys before I figured it out...